# How to identify math formula in .docx / .doc file using java?

Tags: java, parsing, math, docx

In my project,i am reading data from .docx file using XWPFWordExtractor class object but the problem is with mathematical formulas/equations those i want to identify while reading. Can we identify that the next line / next place is a mathematical formula/equation ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of mathematical equation, and the kind of text. And the way used to write the formulas.

- If the formulas are embedded objects from some OLE formula editor, then the information that these are external objects should be present in the document, although I don't know what the extractor does about them.
- If the formulas are plain text, then it would be easy enough to distinguish lines containing only digits, elementary arithmetic operations, one kind of parentheses and equals signs from those which contain other text.
- If your formulas are more complicated, and your text uses some math vocabulary as well, the line between text and formula might become blurred.
- If you really mean “equation” in the literal sense, then chances are that anything containing “=” is an equation, and anything else is not.
- If there is some common formatting for equations, e.g. common indentation or font or style class or whatever, you might be able to use that.